# Duda sobre lanzar notificaciones en segundo plano en android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications, background

vereis, estoy haciendo un aplicación de android que consiste en una lista de tareas, en la cual el usuario registra una tarea para cierta fecha, y cuando llega la fecha le manda una notificación con un pending intent que navega al fragmento de detalle de dicha tarea.

La cosa es que no consigo dar con el clavo he intentado hacer uso de servicios en segundo plano, pero no termina de funcionar porque cuando el dispositivo se apaga obviamente estas tareas programadas usando coroutines desaparecen y aparte de esto también tenemos el ciclo de vida del servicio el cual como tal no se puede controlar y tenemos el problema de que estas coroutines no se ejecuten o simplemente se eliminen por acabar el ciclo de vida del servicio que las acogen.

Estoy intentando usar un jobservice, pero por lo visto esto no es lo que se debería de hacer, y la verdad es que llevo bastante tiempo atascado en esta funcionalidad (unas tres o cuatro semanas).

Me podríais dar algún consejo sobre como implementar esto o en su defecto documentación, porque todo lo que veo no termina de encajar y la verdad es que estoy bastante perdido.

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor, añade el código que te causa errores y lo que has intentado para solucionarlo para que puedas recibir respuestas óptimas

Comment: puedes usar el [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms)

Comment: Prueba workmanager, sobrevivie al reinicio del dispositivo

Comment: @ManuelMato muchisimas gracias por darme el consejo me puse a investigar sobre como usar workmanager y la verdad es que era lo que necesitaba, eres un grande